# Difference between "pain" and "ache"

Tags: differences, nouns, synonyms

What's the difference between *pain* and *ache*?

I often see the two words used (almost) interchangeably. At the same time the phrase "aches and pains" [is pretty common](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=aches%20and%20pains), and seems to suggest that the two words aren't exact synonyms.

The dictionary definitions I've seen ("ache is a continuous dull pain") don't really help in understanding many of the usages I've come across, such as [this one](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/back-pain/Pages/Introduction.aspx) from the NHS:

> Back pain [...] usually feels like an ache

and also [this title](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/stomach-ache-abdominal-pain/Pages/Introduction.aspx):

> Stomach ache and abdominal pain

It would be particularly interesting to see examples where one of the two words is appropriate when describing physical suffering, and the other isn't.

Comment: Ache is persistent pain. Pain is a a sensation characterized by physical discomfort. This cannot suffice as an answer and so I have mentioned this in comment

Comment: and what is your native language, in which "ache" and "pain" don't have different translations?

Comment: Don't worry about the close votes - they'll fade away in about a week.

Comment: All aches are pains, but not all pains are aches. Seems to mostly be defined by how one *feels* regarding the pain. (Just felt I'd throw this in. Definitely not worth an answer).

Comment: There are also two Chinese characters describing *ache* or *pain* &ndash; 疼 and 痛. Intriguingly, they can be synonymous, although some say the former is more mental, while the latter more physiological.

Answer (score 21):

This is a difficult question to answer, because both aches and pains are subjective experiences - like colours - which you're unable to share, but assume everybody understands. I would have assumed that every language has words for both ache and pain, so a dictionary would tell you the difference in an instant. But, I would also assume you've done that, so your native language might not (I'm interested to find out what language that is).

An ache is a persistent discomfort, typically dull so that you can try to ignore it, but sometimes all-encompassing, yet not sharp enough to describe as pain. Your legs would ache after a tough run; you would not describe this as pain. You usually get a headache, not a head pain. You would suffer pain when you cut your finger, then experience an ache as the wound heals.

A pain is something more localised, often (but not always) short-lived, and something you'd be less able to ignore.

When you receive an injection, there is a pain as the needle goes in. During the following days, the surrounding area will ache.

There is considerable overlap between the two, and it would be quite acceptable to say "the ache in my shoulder is painful".

Poets and songwriters quite often speak of their heart *aching*. This fits well with a persistent sense of yearning or melancholy. If they said there was a *pain* in their heart, it would suggest a quite different emotion.

Describing pain and discomfort is difficult and subjective; I imagine in any language. When a doctor asks you how much something hurts, how can you explain in a reliable way?

Comment: (+1) Thank you for this. In Russian there's a single word (*боль*) for both *ache* and *pain*.

Comment: (+1) In German it is a single word (*Schmerz*), too.

Comment: Hungarian has a single word (*fájdalom*), too. It seems the distinction between *ache* and *pain* is not nearly as universal as you suppose. The phrase "aches and pains" is more likely a result of the English habit to use two words where one would suffice, e.g. *aid and abet*.

Comment: "Ache" also implies a relatively mild, persistant discomfort. If someone was being tortured with his eyes burned out with red hot pokers, you wouldn't call this an "ache", you'd call it "pain".

Comment: In Sweden, we have "värk" for ache, and "smärta" for pain.

Comment: @Paxinum: In English, a *pain* can *smart*, but usually an *ache* doesn't. To do with the "sudden" connotations of *smart* in other contexts, I imagine.

Comment: (+1) Interesting. Here in Brazil, there is a single word for it, and it's "dor" for both ache and pain. :D

Comment: @NPE: not exactly correct, ache = ноет, pain = болит.

Comment: In Lithuanian we have several words for... this feeling. One is general (*skausmas*, translated *pain*) and then several others to define the type of pain and "ache" is translated as only one of those

Comment: In spanish we don't have two commonly used words, just one. There, obviously, are synonyms and similar words but mostly there is a single word.

Answer (score 7):

"You shall know a word by the company it keeps." Collocations for adjectives coming immediately before *pain*: *chronic, physical, severe, abdominal, sharp,* and *great;* 
and for *ache*: *dull, minor, familiar, joint, constant, little,* and *physical*.

More general collocations for *pain*: *feel, cause, pain, chest, chronic, suffer, ease, suffering,* and *severe;* and for *ache*: *pain, feel, muscle, stomach, dull, heart,* and *body.*

Comment: It's true *sharp pain* is common, whereas *sharp ache* is virtually unknown. But *chronic/constant pain* are also common, even though those words should more properly be associated with *aches*. I think the bottom line is *pain* is the more generic term in the first place - anything that hurts is a *pain*, but an *ache* normally implies a dull, non-localised, persistent pain even without qualifiers.

Comment: OP has already cited examples, generally misleading and unhelpful enough to ask this question here it seems. Never, never cite collocations as canonical.

Answer (score 3):

In many contexts the two words are synonymous. I doubt many people who speak of their *aches and pains* particularly think they're describing two different things, any more than when they say, for example, *not in any way, shape, or form*.

As @Incognito mentions in a comment, *ache* often means persistent *pain*. I would also add that *pain* often implies more extreme or localised discomfort than *ache*.

Apart from that, there are all sorts of idiomatic usages that primarily or exclusively use one or the other. A *pain in the neck* can be applied to a tiresome person, for example, and *heartache* is so commonly used metaphorically for emotional distress that it's normally written as a single word.

Comment: of course they are different things. My shoulder aches from wearing a backpack all day; my hand hurts where I just burned it on the cooker. I have an ache and a pain. Together with the other various things wrong with my body, I have *aches and pains*.

Comment: @slim: To you, perhaps, the two words *always* mean significantly different things. But look at how common [lower back pain](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lower+back+pain%2Clower+backache%2Clower+back+ache&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is compared to the "ache" versions. Despite the fact that in nearly such usage, the thing being spoken of is definitely what you would call an "ache", not a "pain".

Answer (score 1):

In one sense, pain and ache are synonyms. However, an ache is a dull, prolonged pain (my legs ached for hours after the hike), while pain can be any type of physical discomfort (I felt a sharp pain when my arm brushed the thorny bush).

Comment: Could be. This could make for a great answer if you cite the sources of your information.

Answer (score -1):

Pain is a broader term. Ache can be a part of it. Pain often draw our mind to severity and medical emergency. On the other hand ache is temporary discomfort and rarely needs medical emergency.

Comment: See my comment at Sanjay. Personal opinions and perceptions can be posted as comments when you get the privilege to do that. Wait until then.